# NodeJs: pipe tar file from http response to tar.Extract?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, httpresponse, tar

Following task:

We have a nodejs client (daemon) downloading audio data which is contained in a tar file (NOT tar.gz - it really is uncompressed!) from Amazon S3.

At the moment, we glue the chunks together in the 'data' handler of the response, save the whole buffer to disc as a file and then call tar.Extract(inPath, outPath) on the newly created file.

I'd like to skip the process of writing the data to disc and instead pass the data from the response directly to tar.Extract().

This is my handler code:

```
var readResponseData = function (response) {
    response.setEncoding('binary');
    response.pipe(tar.Extract( { path: '/tmp/testyeah' }));
    ....
    ....
```

I always get "Error: Invalid tar file"

I also tried without success the suggestions from this page (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/A7jz6b9daZc) although that should apply to compressed tar files and not the uncompressed ones that we use.

Any suggestions?

Comment: (In order to display code properly in SO, you need to insert an empty line between your text and the code block).

Comment: I got it already, but thank you very much!

Comment: What about removing the `response.setEncoding()` method call? This could convert data in the wrong encoding format, thus resulting in invalid files.

Comment: `request(...).pipe(tar.Extract(...))` works just fine for me on `.tar` files. Try piping the response to `process.stdout` to see what's being fed to `tar.Extract`.

Comment: Paul's suggestion was absolutely correct. Removing that line leads to the code executing properly. Thank you all very much!